# I'm having issue with null safety in my todo app

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, dart-null-safety

I'm trying to assign values but flutter is showing null safety error...

```
List<Todo> todoFromFirestore(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
  if (snapshot != null) {
    return snapshot.docs.map((e) {
      return Todo(
        isComplet: e.data()["isComplet"],
        title: e.data()["title"],
        uid: e.id,
      );
    }).toList();
  } else {
    return [];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this way

```dart
List<Todo> todoFromFirestore(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
  if (snapshot != null) {
    return snapshot.docs.map((e) {
      final map = e.data() as Map?;
      return Todo(
        isComplet: map?["isComplet"] ?? false,
        title: map?["title"] ?? "null",
        uid: e.id,
      );
    }).toList();
  } else {
    return [];
  }
}
```

Comment: Glad to help, you check more about [null-safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety) and [getting firestore data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data)